# How to add string to jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, string, css-selectors

I'm trying to select an id that changes on different posts of same page. So the they have been given an id="show_posts_{PostID}"  - on the final output the {PostID} is replaced with a number. In the function I need to call `$('show_posts_XXXXXX')` - XXXXXX being the generated ID. I have stored this ID in a variable called postId.

But I can't seem to do this `$("'" + "show_posts_" + postId + "'")`

Can anyone tell me how I can add a string to the end of a selector?

Comment: You know what? I didn't even realize I had to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I personally don't think that the SO site makes that clear enough, but whatever. Glad to see that you've gotten the info you needed here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should work. If it does, you'll kick yourself. Don't forget the hash for the ID, and the extra quotation marks aren't necessary.

```
$("#show_posts_" + postId)
```

Comment: You're right I am kicking myself. I started with exactly that. Then it wasn't working and I started second guessing. I realized that it wasn't the selector that I was having issues with! Thanks

Comment: No probs. We all make simple mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the '#' character at the start of the string.

```
$('#show_posts_' + postId)
```

Also, you're trying to stuff the quotes in there in your example, and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I started with exactly that. Then it wasn't working and I started second guessing. I realized that it wasn't the selector that I was having issues with! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

just use `$("#show_posts_"+postID)`

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. To select an element with a given
   ID, you need a `#` character at the
   beginning of the ID.
2. Don't add the quotes to the beginning and end of the string.

Thus:

```
$('#show_posts_' + postId)
```